# Hibernate @OneToMany @ManyToOne inserting into multiple tables

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
CREATE TABLE `Policy` (
`policyId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`policyName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`roleId` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`policyId`)
 CONSTRAINT `policy_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`roleId`) REFERENCES `Role` (`roleId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Role` (
`roleId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`rolename` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`roleDescription` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`roleId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have a 1-Many mapping for the Role-Policy table described and the POJO as follows

```
@Entity
@Table(name="policy")
public class AWSPolicy implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "policyId")
private int policyId;

@Column(name = "policyName")
private String policyName;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="roleId")
private Role role;

public AWSRole getRole() {
    return role;
}
public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public int getPolicyId() {
    return policyId;
}
public void setPolicyId(int policyId) {
    this.policyId = policyId;
}

public String getPolicyName() {
    return policyName;
}
public void setPolicyName(String policyName) {
    this.policyName = policyName;
}

}




@Entity
@Table(name="role")
public class Role implements Serializable{

@Column(name = "rolename")
private String rolename;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "roleId")
private int roleId;


@Column(name = "roleDescription")
private String roleDescription;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "role")
private Set<AWSPolicy> policies;

public Set<AWSPolicy> getPolicies() {
    return policies;
}
public void setPolicies(Set<AWSPolicy> policyList) {
    this.policies = policyList;
}

public int getRoleId() {
    return roleId;
}
public void setRoleId(int roleId) {
    this.roleId = roleId;
}

public String getRolename() {
    return rolename;
}
public void setRolename(String rolename) {
    this.rolename = rolename;
}

public String getRoleDescription() {
    return roleDescription;
}
public void setRoleDescription(String roleDescription) {
    this.roleDescription = roleDescription;
}
}
```

The issue is that when I try to insert into the table , it inserts only into the Role table but not the policy table. Can someone help me with this.

```
    Role role = new Role();
    Set<Policy> policyList = new HashSet<Policy>();
    Policy policy = new Policy();
    policy.setPolicyName("uberpolicy");
    policyList.add(policy);

    role.setRolename("uberrole");
    role.setRoleDescription("uberrole");     

    role.setPolicies(policyList);

    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.save(role);
```

Comment: You could see the sql query that hibernate executes in debug mode.
Did you check that?

Comment: Enable show_sql=true and paste the queries that get executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the fix

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cas_aws_role")
public class AWSRole implements Serializable{

@Column(name = "casAWSRolename")
private String casAWSRolename;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "casAWSRoleId")
private int casAWSRoleId;

@Column(name = "casAWSRoleDisplayName")
private String casAWSRoleDisplayName;


@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="casAWSRoleId")
private Set<AWSPolicy> policies = new HashSet<AWSPolicy>();

// method to manage the bidirectional association
public void addToPolicies(AWSPolicy awsPolicy) {
    this.policies.add(awsPolicy);
    awsPolicy.setAWSRole(this);
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="casAWSRolesetId")
private AWSRoleset awsRoleset;

public AWSRoleset getAWSRoleset() {
    return awsRoleset;
}
public void setAWSRoleset(AWSRoleset awsRoleset) {
    this.awsRoleset = awsRoleset;
}


public Set<AWSPolicy> getPolicies() {
    return policies;
}
public void setPolicies(Set<AWSPolicy> policyList) {
    this.policies = policyList;
}

public int getCasAWSRoleId() {
    return casAWSRoleId;
}
public void setCasAWSRoleId(int casAWSRoleId) {
    this.casAWSRoleId = casAWSRoleId;
}

public String getCasAWSRolename() {
    return casAWSRolename;
}
public void setCasAWSRolename(String casAWSRolename) {
    this.casAWSRolename = casAWSRolename;
}


public String getCasAWSRoleDisplayName() {
    return casAWSRoleDisplayName;
}
public void setCasAWSRoleDisplayName(String casAWSRoleDisplayName) {
    this.casAWSRoleDisplayName = casAWSRoleDisplayName;
}

}


@Entity
@Table(name="cas_aws_policy")
public class AWSPolicy implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "casAWSPolicyId")
private int casAWSPolicyId;

@Column(name = "casAWSPolicyName")
private String casAWSPolicyName;


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="casAWSRoleId")
private AWSRole awsRole;

public AWSRole getAWSRole() {
    return awsRole;
}
public void setAWSRole(AWSRole awsRole) {
    this.awsRole = awsRole;
}


public int getCasAWSPolicyId() {
    return casAWSPolicyId;
}
public void setCasAWSPolicyId(int casAWSPolicyId) {
    this.casAWSPolicyId = casAWSPolicyId;
}

public String getCasAWSPolicyName() {
    return casAWSPolicyName;
}
public void setCasAWSPolicyName(String casAWSPolicyName) {
    this.casAWSPolicyName = casAWSPolicyName;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this example will help you
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/
Can you please remove cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST and try.

Can you please write output of you query so I can help you.

Comment: I did enable the mysql logging. I see the hibernate query but nothing gets inserted

Hibernate: insert into role (roleDescription,  role name) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into policy (role_roleId, policyName) values (?, ?)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code that you post. I see the insert queries being executed on the ROLE and POLICY tables but the value in roleId column of the POLICY table is null. This is because you have set the role object in the policy instance. You have to set both ends of a relationship.

The below code should update the foreign key value

```
    Role role = new Role();
    Set<Policy> policyList = new HashSet<Policy>();
    Policy policy = new Policy();
    policy.setPolicyName("uberpolicy");

    policy.setRole(role);      //Set the role object in the policy through a setter.

    policyList.add(policy);

    role.setRolename("uberrole");
    role.setRoleDescription("uberrole");     

    role.setPolicies(policyList);

    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.save(role);
```